# Is there a way to create a dynamic Query on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm creating a database on Google Sheets for work and while I'm aware it's not the best solution, due to a number of restraints, that's what I've got to work with atm.

The thing is, I'm creating this for people who don't really know how to work with formulas on Google Sheets so I'm trying to be as user friendly as I can.

I'll use this sample sheet to try and demonstrate what I'm trying to do:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tXM0IlswQVdwFum9a0pR5NsbtL5Uq_AH1tPbytXGvVg/edit#gid=0

One of the sheets is the Database, which will countain multiple columns of data (there's 10 on the sample, but the actual database is much larger).

There is another sheet called Column Index where I have a list of all columns, what kind of data they represent and a checkbox for people to select what data they want.

Finally, theres a third sheet called Data Extraction and I want to get the checked columns from the Database and send them to this sheet so people can download or copy this data to other worksheet.

It looks like a QUERY situation to me, but I'm not sure if it's possible to do it dynamically

Comment: I mean I'm not sure how to structure it in a way that all the users have to do is check the boxes and the data they chose will appear on the "Data Extraction" sheet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(
    Database!A:K, 
    "select A,"&
    TEXTJOIN(
        ",",
        1,
        IFNA(
            REGEXEXTRACT(
                ADDRESS(
                    1,
                    MATCH(
                        IF(
                            'Column Index'!C2:C,
                            'Column Index'!B2:B,
                            ""
                        ),
                        Database!1:1,
                        0
                    )
                ),
                "[A-Z]+"
            )
        )
    )
))
```

I built the query string, selecting the column indices that we wanted. No need for the "Col Index" Column.

Using Address, we can generate the appropriate column letter using a column address, then we just extract the letters part with a regex.

Answer (score 2):

What I got was not that different as I also tried to construct the query string. The downside is it may be a bit buggy (but it works)

Here it is:

`=query(Database!A1:K15,"select A,"&join(",",ArrayFormula(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,filter(row('Column Index'!C2:C11),'Column Index'!C2:C11),4), "1", ""))))`